# Как получить из лямбды значение, которое она вернёт?

Tags: c++, lambda

Я бы хотел таким образом получить максимальный элемент `field`, но не понимаю, как получить возвращаемое значение.

```
int res = [field](){
            int max = 0;
            for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
                for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++)
                    if (field[a][b].value > max)
                        max = field[a][b].value;
            return max;
        };
        qDebug() << "Record = " + QString::number(k);
```

Comment: Ну так вызовите вашу лямбду.

Comment: https://ideone.com/vtLH1G

Comment: если в массиве field все элементы отрицательны, то результат может удивить.

Comment: @KoVadim а чему удивляться, 0 и будет. А за такой код сори, надо было один раз использовать с известными значениями

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вопрос о лямбде (а не о том, что она делает), то:

```
int res = [field](){ 
    ...
    return max;
}();
```

Обратите внимание на скобочки `()` после закрывающей фигурной скобки.

Но! если лямбда нужна один раз - то зачем с ней заморачиваться вообще?

А если несколько - то советовал бы

```
auto f = [field](){ 
    ...
    return max;
};

...

int res = f();
```